# Dynamically create class attributes

Tags: python, class-attributes

I need to dynamically create class attributes from a DEFAULTS dictionary.

```
defaults = {
    'default_value1':True,
    'default_value2':True,
    'default_value3':True,
}

class Settings(object):
    default_value1 = some_complex_init_function(defaults[default_value1], ...)
    default_value2 = some_complex_init_function(defaults[default_value2], ...)
    default_value3 = some_complex_init_function(defaults[default_value3], ...)
```

I could also achive this by having sth. like `__init__` for class creation, in order to dynamically create these attributes from dictionary and save a lot of code and stupid work.

How would you do this?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 32):

You could do it without metaclasses using decorators. This way is a bit more clear IMO:

```
def apply_defaults(cls):
    defaults = {
        'default_value1':True,
        'default_value2':True,
        'default_value3':True,
    }
    for name, value in defaults.items():
        setattr(cls, name, some_complex_init_function(value, ...))
    return cls

@apply_defaults
class Settings(object):
    pass
```

Prior to Python 2.6 class decorators were unavailable. So you can write:

```
class Settings(object):
    pass
Settings = apply_defaults(Settings)
```

in older versions of python.

In the provided example `apply_defaults` is reusable… Well, except that the defaults are hard-coded in the decorator's body :) If you have just a single case you can even simplify your code to this:

```
defaults = {
    'default_value1':True,
    'default_value2':True,
    'default_value3':True,
}

class Settings(object):
    """Your implementation goes here as usual"""

for name, value in defaults.items():
    setattr(Settings, name, some_complex_init_function(value, ...))
```

This is possible since classes (in the sense of types) are objects themselves in Python.

Comment: You also need to return the "decorated" class (`cls` in the first example) at the end of the decorator function, don't you? Took me a while to figure out, but unless I do this the class will equal `None` after definition. Am I missing something, like for example some way of supplying the class by reference instead?

Comment: How do i pass defaults to the file like this `a = Settings(defaults)`  `settings.py` is a particular file

Answer (score 5):

I think that's case for metaclass:

```
class SettingsMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        for name, value in defaults.items():
            dct[name] = some_complex_init_function(value, ...)
        return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)

class Settings(object):
    __metaclass__ = SettingsMeta
```

Comment: how do we pass defaults, or how can we initialize any object of this Settings Class

Comment: same question with @vijayshanker

Comment: The code depends on the `defaults` dictionary being in scope when defining `Settings` class.

Comment: `SettingsMeta` and `Settings` in the setting.py file? How do i pass defaults parameter to it?

Comment: With the current code, you cannot pass anything, the `defaults` dictionary is taken from the scope, defined before `Settings` class. To be able to pass the defaults, you would need to restructure it. But it feels like a different question to the one asked originally.

Answer (score 2):

When defining a class, the local namespace will be converted into the class namespace at the conclusion of the class body.  As such, you can accomplish this with:

```
class Settings(object):
    for key, val in defaults.iteritems():
        locals()[key] = some_complex_init_function(val, ...)
```

Comment: -1 The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=locals#locals) for `locals()` says the contents of the dictionary returned should not be modified.