# Initialize a list of field in a form using Wtforms

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

Hi so suppose I have a list of forms:

```
class Create(Form):
    cols = []
    for col in ['colA', 'colB', 'colC']:
        cols.append(TextAreaField(col))
```

When this gets initialized here:

```
@app.route('/some/path')
def create():
    form = Create()
    return render_template('index.html', form=form)
```

I want to make sure all these `TextAreaField` get converted into `<textarea id="col#", name="col#"><textarea>`. As right now they stay as `<UnboundedField(TextAreaField, ('col#,),{})>` objects. Right now they are not getting converted

If this is possible any recommendation would be great. Thanks!

```
<div class="row">
     {% for col in form.cols %}
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="form-group">
        {{ col(rows="20") }}
        {% for error in col.errors %}
            <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

`AttributeError: 'UnboundField' object has no attribute '__call__'`

It obviously works when I have them all separately:

```
class Create(Form):
    cols = []
    colA = TextAreaField('colA')
    colB = TextAreaField('colB')
    colC = TextAreaField('colC')
```

Otherwise I wouldnt be asking the question

Comment: Have you tried anything? What's your html template look like?

Comment: <div class="row">
         {% for col in form.cols %}
     <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
            {{ col(rows="20") }}
            {% for error in col.errors %}
                <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
            {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

AttributeError: 'UnboundField' object has no attribute 'process'

@CodeLikeBeaker

Comment: @CodeLikeBeaker I did......

Comment: Please take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43859978/add-fields-dynamically-to-wtforms-form