# Can I add large numbers of filters programmatically

Tags: django, django-filter, metaclass

I have a table with about 30 columns and I'd like to attach five filters to most columns in a highly repetitive manner. So I hoped that I could use a class decorator to define them as per [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583620/dynamically-create-class-attributes). No joy. `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable` (at runtime when I invoke the view)

Anyway, then I read up about "proper" metaclassing and tried

```
class SettingsMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, attrs):

        for name in ('fx_t', 'status'): # just two for now but target ~60 with 5 different lookup_expr
            attr_name = name + '_start'
            attrs[attr_name] =  FD.CharFilter( 
                field_name = name,
                lookup_expr = 'istartswith' ,
                label =  name.replace('_t','').capitalize() + ' starts with',
            )  
        return super(SettingsMeta, cls).__new__(cls, clsname, bases, uppercase_attrs)

class SelectMaskdataFilters( FD.FilterSet, metaclass=SettingsMeta): 
    class Meta:
        model = Maskdata
        fields = {
            'notes':        [ 'icontains',],
        }
    #status_sw = FD.CharFilter( field_name='status', lookup_expr='startswith')
    ...
```

Again no joy: `TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases` at server start-up.

SelectMaskDataFilters is itself working as expected in a view if I just  remove `metaclass=SettingsMeta`

I'm in over my head, but I really don't like repeating myself with a hundred or so filter definitions all of which will be almost the same. So, does anybody know how to define a large number of filters in in a FilterSet other than  copy, paste, and error-prone small changes?  Note, most of the filters will use `method=` not `lookup_expr=` so the `fields` attribute in the inner `Meta` class is not useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define these in the local scope of the `SelectMaskdataFilters`:

```
import django_filters

class SelectMaskdataFilters(django_filters.FilterSet):
    for name in ('fx_t', 'status'):
        label = name.replace('_t','').capitalize()
        locals()[f'{name}_start'] = django_filters.CharFilter( 
            field_name=name,
            lookup_expr='istartswith' ,
            label=f'{label} starts with'
        )
    
    class Meta:
        model = Maskdata
        fields = {
            'notes': [ 'icontains',],
        }
```

Comment: Very many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The metaclass conflict error is due to the fact the class you are inherting from (`FD.FilterSet`) already uses a custom metaclass. So, if you inherit your from `type`, Python has conflicting metaclasses that it can't make work nicely together: which `metaclass.__new__` method should be called? The one in your metaclass or in the FD.FilterSet metaclass.

The way to make that work properly is to make your metaclasses work colaboratively, and have a single metaclass that resolves the conflicts. In this case, all you have to do is to inherit of the metaclass of `FD.FieldSet` itself instead of `type`. (and, of course, call the superclass's methods were needed)

You can use the one-parameter form of type to get the proper metaclass, you don't even need to import it explicitly.

In your listing, just change this line:

```
class SettingsMeta(type):
```

for

```
class SettingsMeta(type(FD.FilterSet)):
```

and everything should work (with no need to repeat yourself in the class body for each of your models)