How to dynamically define class variables?
Let's say I want to create a class:
class Foo:
    hello = "world"
    goodbye = "moon"

But both of those class variables are dynamically provided.
attrs = [("hello", "world"), ("goodbye", "moon")]


def create_class(attrs):

    class Foo:
        # INSERT DYNAMIC ATTRS HERE
        pass


create_class(attrs)

How can I dynamically set those attributes as class variables at the time the class is defined? I know I can use setattr to set them after the class is created, but this is not what I'm looking for.
I'm thinking this is possible with __build_class__ but I'm struggling to implement it myself.

Did you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583620/dynamically-create-class-attributes ?

You can do this by using the type function. It looks like this....
attrs = [("hello", "world"), ("goodbye", "moon")]

def create_class(attrs):
    # Create a dictionary of the attributes
    attr_dict = dict(attrs)
    
    # Use the type function to create the class dynamically
    Foo = type('Foo', (object,), attr_dict)
    
    return Foo

# Create the class
my_class = create_class(attrs)

# Check the attributes
print(my_class.hello)    # Output: world
print(my_class.goodbye)  # Output: moon

If you want to inherit then you just pass that to the types arg in the second tuple.
# Define a base class
class BaseClass:
    base_attr = "base"

    def base_method(self):
        return "This is a method from BaseClass"

# Attributes to be added to the new class
attrs = [("hello", "world"), ("goodbye", "moon")]

def create_class(attrs, base_classes):
    # Create a dictionary of the attributes
    attr_dict = dict(attrs)
    
    # Use the type function to create the class dynamically with inheritance
    Foo = type('Foo', base_classes, attr_dict)
    
    return Foo

# Create the class, inheriting from BaseClass
my_class = create_class(attrs, (BaseClass,))

# Check the attributes
print(my_class.hello)    # Output: world
print(my_class.goodbye)  # Output: moon

# Check inherited attributes and methods
print(my_class.base_attr)               # Output: base
print(my_class().base_method())         # Output: This is a method


You can simplify: attr_dict = dict(attrs). But at that point, it's so short and self-descriptive you might as well inline it: type('Foo', (object,), dict(attrs))

Plus 1, that is more concise. Added and edit but didn't do it inline just to make it a bit more readable for those unfamiliar with type.

You can also leave out object if you don't need Python 2 compatibility: type('Foo', (), ...)

Is it possible to also inherit from another class within this definition? I know this is outside the scope of my initial question, which this does answer.

@Matt yes,  I'll add that example too.

@Matt Yeah, you just specify a different bases argument, like (int,) instead of (object,). See docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type

Ah, I was trying to add it like (object, int) which was failing but your suggestion is correct @wjandrea

@Matt Yeah, that'd have to be (int, object). But IDK if that'd work perfectly in Python 2. In Python 3, you can (and probably should) leave out object since int is a subclass of object.
